# IntelliJ IDEA: Unable to download MySqlDriver

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA,and I want to configure MySQL database from the IDE:
[image]

then fail:
[image]

The error is:

Failed to download 'http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

I don't know why connection will time out.

I can download other things such as plugins from jetbrains, but except jdbc-drivers.

Comment: Do you use something like proxy?

Comment: No，I have shut down my proxy, but still not work. The point is that I can still download plugins from IDEA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend taking a look in IDEA's log files to see if they may have additional details as to why the download is timing out. From the menu go to *Help > Show log*.

As a **workaround**, you can manually download the drivers and place them in the necessary location. Download bo the JAR and the `mysql-connector-license.txt` license file (from http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-license.txt of from MySQL directly). Place both files in the path `{idea-config-dir}/jdbc-drivers/MySQL Connector/J/5.1.40` (modifying the version number if necessary). The location of the `{idea-config-dir}` can be looked up in the [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) help document. For example, `c:\Users\User\.IntelliJIdea2017\config` or `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017`

Thus, in the end, that directory should have two files:

1. `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar`
2. `mysql-connector-license.txt`

Comment: thank you. The workaround really works. I just direct download the jar (from http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar) and  the mysql-connector-license.txt license file (from http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/jdbc-drivers/mysql-connector-license.txt), and place them in ```~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017/jdbc-drivers/MySQL Connector/J/5.1.40```. Hope help others too.

Answer (score 2):

put jars in

C:\Users\UUSER\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\DataGrip2020.1\jdbc-drivers\PostgreSQL\42.2.5

from another install with internet

Answer (score 0):

In 2019, the folder is this :

```
C:\Users\YouUser\.DataGrip2019.3\config\jdbc-drivers\MySQL Connector\J 8\8.0.21
```

Download jar from :
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar